# Homotopy Equivalence of Posets for the Weyl Group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

How do I go about proving Quillen's Homotopy Equivalence of Chevalley (subgroups of) automorphism groups of finite classical Lie algebras. Given $\sigma$ , such that Chevalley’s construction $GU$$n$($q$) is obtained from $GL$$n$($q^2$) by twisting.

$\sigma$ defines an automorphism ($a_{i,j}$) $\rightarrow$ ($a^{q}_{i,j})^{−tr}$ of $GL_n(q^2)$.
Then $GU_n(q)$ = $GL_n(q^2)^\sigma$

The proof in and out of itself should enforce the existance of posets $S_p(G)$ consisting of non-identity p-subgroups of a finite group $G$, which are homotopy equivalent to the subposet $A_p(G)$
consisting of non-identity elementary abelian p-subgroups.

Comment: This question is not coherent and should be reworded and maybe writing a shorter question would help.  Voting to close. 

Comment: Fair game, Steinberg. Don't flag what you can't understand.

Comment: I did not flag. But like your last post the question doesn't make sense. Automorphisms, for example, don't have subgroups. The posets you mention exist already for any finite group and so the proof doesn't need to enforce them.  And if memory serves the homotopy equivalence you speak of doesn't need Chevalley groups. One uses Quillen's Theorem A. 

Comment: Thank you, Steinberg. Isn't the commutator group a vague but still valid example of a subgroup of an automorphism, i'm thinking about the torsion group and the invariant properties? I am sure I could tackle that certain automorphisms can be broken down into certain subgroups.

I appreciate your response :)

Comment: The composition of two inner automorphisms is again an inner automorphism (as mentioned above: (xa)b=xab, and with this operation, the collection of all inner automorphisms of G is itself a group, the inner automorphism group of G denoted Inn(G).
 
Inn(G) is a normal subgroup of the full automorphism group Aut(G) of G.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism

Comment: You can have a group of automorphisms and hence a subgroup of the group of automorphisms but not a subgroup of an automorphism. 

Comment: It's all in the wording!

Comment: Edited per your request! Agreed it looks more reasonable. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The homotopy equivalence of the two posets is discussed in this question [Status of Quillen's conjecture on elementary abelian p-groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38890/status-of-quillens-conjecture-on-elementary-abelian-p-groups) and its answers.  The first part of the question I maintain makes little sense and needs to be reformulated.